# Good jQuery plugin for image zoom in an absolute position div to the side? (like ecommerce sites)

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

Looking at something like http://www.express.com/clothing/limited+edition+extra+slim+1mx+shirt+to+easy+care/pro/0308116/cat810040 where the zoom is carried out in an absolute position div to the side

Found a few such as Easyzoom - wondering if there are opinions on flexible plugins, recommendations from experience

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most well-known jQuery plugin that can be used to zoom parts of an image is [cloudzoom](http://www.starplugins.com/cloudzoom), however it's non-free.

There are a lot of image zoom plugins in this page:

http://netfruits.com/2013/03/jquery-image-zoom-plugins/

Some nice free ones:

- [Easyzoom](http://i-like-robots.github.io/EasyZoom/) is probably the closest to what you require that is free, as you mentioned.
- There's also [elevate-zoom](http://www.elevateweb.co.uk/image-zoom), which is free and looks quite nice.

Otherwise, if you're willing to pay, cloudzoom is the most versatile and feature rich, AFAIK.